# Set default for Types.Money in KeystoneJS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

How do I set a default for Types.Money in KeystoneJS?

This I know there isn't an option for it — and this won't work.

```
price: { type: Types.Money, format: '$0,0.00', currency: 'en-gb', default: '50'}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Just updated Keystone. Previous version didn't support it... current one does. : < oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported with the current version of KeystoneJS.

I couldn't find it in the change logs but it definitely works now.
https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/HISTORY.md